# Validate: Only allow letters, numbers, spaces, hyphens, and apostrophes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I tried doing it like this:

```
validates :name, :format => { :with => /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 -']+$/ }
```

However, it allows ! as well.
How could I change the code so it can only allow letters, numbers, spaces, hyphens, and apostrophes in the name and that it will start with a letter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You didn't escape the `-` amid of your regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 \-']+$
                     ^ here
```

If you place `-` inside the character class `[]`(between two characetrs) then you must escape this with escape character(i.e. `\`). Otherwise it means a range. For your case it was between the `space` and `'`. Which means any characters those reside from `space`(ascii value) to `'`(ascii value). And unfortunately the `!` resides in that range.

Comment: Oops! Thanks! Regex is so confusing for me.